# tomcat log not showing com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.logClasses Root resource classes found

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I am deploying war into two `instances(containers)`, where same `tomcat image` was deployed.. when I deploy my war in first instance it showing the following `log` and working fine

```
25-Jan-2018 11:06:29.523 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] 
com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init Scanning for root 
resource and provider classes in the packages:
io.swagger.jaxrs.json
io.swagger.jaxrs.listing
com.example.metrics.service
com.example.batch.service
com.example.metrics.rest
25-Jan-2018 11:06:29.599 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] 
com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.logClasses Root resource 
classes found:
class com.nuovo.streamseer.sentinel.metrics.service.SentinelMetricService
class com.example.batch.service.BatchDataService
class com.example.rest.ProcessorDataRS
class com.example.metrics.rest.DataRS
class io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource
class com.example.metrics.rest.CombinedRS
class com.example.metrics.rest.AlterRS
25-Jan-2018 11:06:29.599 INFO [localhost-startStop-2]         
com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.logClasses Provider classes found:
class io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers
class io.swagger.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
25-Jan-2018 11:06:29.719 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] 
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate 
Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.8-ea03 06/10/2011 03:17 PM'
25-Jan-2018 11:06:31.320 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] 
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web 
application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/sat-metrics.war] has finished in [9,964] ms
```

But When I am trying to upload same war(`sat-metrics.war`) into another container, I am getting the following log and its not working

```
25-Jan-2018 11:05:38.056 INFO [localhost-startStop-3] com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
io.swagger.jaxrs.json
io.swagger.jaxrs.listing
com.example.metrics.service
com.example.batch.service
com.example.metrics.rest
25-Jan-2018 11:05:38.112 INFO [localhost-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/sat-metrics.war] has finished in [7,462] ms
```

The difference I found is in first `container` log it is able to found 'root classes' but in second `container` log there is no `root classes` info.

what might the the issue and how can I solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the issue, there were **two versions of Jersey JAR files** in **WEB-INF/lib** folder. After removing the conflict, it worked.